# how to create date format UTC php

Tags: php, date, format

I have this DateTime format:

`2020-08-27 19:00:00`

and I want convert to this format:

`Thu Aug 27 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia)`

my version php is 5
can i how to do
thanks

Comment: Any code attempt? Neither are formats. Just are how you want the data displayed. So your code attempt will help on providing some suggestions.

Comment: no have php code,  i have the Date and i need convert to this format.

Comment: Its not a "format" as mentioned. It's how the data is displayed. I guess if you insisted you could call that a format. Like "Mr. Joe Smith", "Joe", "Mr. Smith", and "Joe Smith" are all "formats", I guess. .... But without code to go by on what you intend, no idea what you are talking about. Sorry.

Comment: `DateTime` is a class that can be an object. Yes it can be displayed in certain "formats". Where's your code? ... I see what you mean now by "format". But im not seeing any code. Hence my earlier confusion.

Comment: in javascript the code is     ` startTime = new Date(
      Date.UTC(
        date.getUTCFullYear(),
        date.getUTCMonth(),
        date.getUTCDate()
      )
    ); `

Comment: But you state `php` as your language. Truly lost now.

Comment: this code javascript is the idea to php made console.log and see the format to i want

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna throw you a bone here because dates are hard. You can use the basic [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function and [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to do everything you need, the trick is figuring out which [formatting flags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to use. You're gonna have a bad time with [timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), so be prepared to tear some hair out over that. Your date input doesn't have any timezone info, so your output is going to use whatever is [set in your PHP instance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Good luck.

```
<?php
$dateInput = '2020-08-27 19:00:00';

$time = strtotime($dateInput);

/*
Thu Aug 27, 2020 19:00 EDT-0400 (America/New_York)
The timezone will depend on what's set in your PHP instance. Look at date_default_timezone_set
*/
$output = date('D M j, Y H:i TO (e)', $time);
echo $output.PHP_EOL;

/*
Thu Aug 27, 2020 19:00 EDT-0400 (hora estándar de Colombia)
"hora estándar de Colombia" isn't a thing that php dates can do, so you have to hard code it.
Escape all non-format characters. Some are safe, but let's just nuke it from orbit. If this is more than
a one-off, write a function to escape the fancy timezone string.
*/
$output = date('D M j, Y H:i TO \(\h\o\r\a\ \e\s\t\á\n\d\a\r \d\e \C\o\l\o\m\b\i\a)', $time);

echo $output.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thats a big bone Rob

Comment: I'm feeling generous. Sometimes you gotta give back, ya know? Hack the planet.

Comment: Ok RobRuchte. I feel you on that

Comment: Big bone because OP gave no code and thus has no understanding. Even provided javascript as reference to no php code.